# TypeScript module resolution error: 'Could not find a declaration file for module'. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module

I can't add a JS libarary to my TS project. I installed a JS library.

I get the following error, when i try to run a server:

```
`Could not find a declaration file for module 'lyrics-finder'. '' implicitly has an 'any' type.
Try `npm i --save-dev @types/lyrics-finder` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'lyrics-finder';``
```

This library does not have @types/lyrics-finder, so I need to create a new declaration, but I keep failing.

I created lyrics-finder.d.ts file:

```
`declare module 'lyrics-finder' {
  export default function lyricsFinder(artist: string | undefined, title: string | undefined): Promise<string | null>;
}`
```

I put this in types folder. Then I updated a tsconfig.json (added "typeRoots", "baseUrl")

```
*{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "typeRoots": ["src/types"],
    "declaration": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
  },*
```

But all of this did not help and I am still getting the same error that module is not founded.
Do you have any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [NPM page for that project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lyrics-finder), the link to [their github page](https://github.com/alias-rahil/lyrics-searcher) redirects to a similar package but with a different name `lyrics-searcher`

`lyrics-searcher` seems to be [built in TypeScript](https://github.com/alias-rahil/lyrics-searcher/blob/main/src/lib/index.ts) and [has typedefs included in their package](https://github.com/alias-rahil/lyrics-searcher/blob/main/package.json#L6)

So, I think you can probably just use this package instead, it appears to be made by the same developer.  I guess they just renamed it.